# Analytic function satisfying $x^2f''(x) +xf'(x)+x^2f(x)=0$ and $f(0)=1$

Tags: calculus, power-series

> Suppose that the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges for
>   all real $x$ to a function $f(x)$ that satisfies $$x^2f''(x)
>  +xf'(x)+x^2f(x)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad f(0)=1.$$
>
> - Determine $a_0$, $a_1$, and $a_2$.
> - Determine $a_n$ for all $n$.
> - Let $g(x) = f'(x)$. Show that $g(x)$ satisfies $$x^2g''(x) + xg'(x) +    (x^2-1)g(x)=0.$$

I must be making a mistake here, because I'm getting a contradiction. $f$ is analytic so it has continuous derivatives of all orders, in particular at zero. $$f''(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}f''(x) = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{xf'(x)+x^2f(x)}{x^2}\\=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f'(x)}{x}+1,$$ which implies that $f'(x)\to 0$ at zero.

But $f''(0)$ is by definition $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{x}$. So we have $f''(0)=f''(0)+1$. What gives?

Comment: @T.Bongers Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your differential equation, it's true (for $x \ne 0$) that

$$f''(x) = \frac{-xf'(x) - x^2 f(x)}{x^2}$$

Now proceeding as you did, you'll find that

$$f''(0) = - f''(0) - f(0) \implies f''(0) = -\frac 1 2$$